# Error while running Vagrant up

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrantfile

Initially, I had 8 vagrant machines running and something went wrong. So I deleted the vms in ~/VirtualBox\ VMs folder and placed the backup .vmdk files in the same location. 
Then I tried running vagrant up...
But I'm getting the following error

Bringing machine 'virtual-am1' up with 'virtualbox' provider...

```
==> virtual-am1: Importing base box 'centos653'...
==> virtual-am1: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> virtual-am1: Setting the name of the VM: vagrant_virtual-am1_1478100170176_83326
==> virtual-am1: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> virtual-am1: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    virtual-am1: Adapter 1: nat
    virtual-am1: Adapter 2: bridged
==> virtual-am1: Forwarding ports...
    virtual-am1: 22 (guest) => 2203 (host) (adapter 1)
==> virtual-am1: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
   A customization command failed:

["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "virtual-am1"]

The following error was experienced:

#<Vagrant::Errors::VBoxManageError: There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["modifyvm", "6dd13964-e648-40cd-932e-3e18be375d31", "--name", "virtual-am1"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Could not rename the directory '/home/vagrant/VirtualBox VMs/vagrant_virtual-am1_1478100170176_83326' to '/home/vagrant/VirtualBox VMs/virtual-am1' to save the settings file (VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS)

VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component SessionMachine, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports

VBoxManage: error: Context: "SaveSettings()" at line 2788 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp

>Please fix this customization and try again.
```

This is how my Vagrantfile looks like...
We had a custom Vagrant file

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

#Parse nodes config file
nodes_config = (JSON.parse(File.read("nodes.json")))['nodes']

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.ssh.insert_key = false

  config.vm.box = "centos653"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/2creatives/vagrant-centos/releases/download/v6.5.3/centos65-x86_64-20140116.box"
 # config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"

  nodes_config.each do |node|
    node_name   = node[0] # name of node
    node_values = node[1] # content of node

    config.vm.define node_name do |config|
      # configures all forwarding ports in JSON array
      ports = node_values['ports']
      ports.each do |port|
        config.vm.network :forwarded_port,
          host:  port[':host'],
          guest: port[':guest'],
          id:    port[':id']
      end

      config.vm.synced_folder "/bits", "/vagrant/bits"
      config.vm.synced_folder "../virtual", "/vagrant/virtual"

      config.vm.hostname = node_values[':hostname']
      #config.vm.network :private_network, ip: node_values[':ip']
      config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: 'enp134s1f0', ip: node_values[':ip']

      config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", node_values[':memory']]
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", node_values[':node']]
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", 8]
      end

    end
  end
end
```

This is how my nodes.json file looks like

```
{
  "nodes": {
    "virtual-am1": {
      ":node": "virtual-am1",
      ":ip": "192.168.1.50",
      ":hostname": "am1.onefederation.org",
      "ports": [
        {
          ":host": 2203,
          ":guest": 22,
          ":id": "ssh"
        }
      ],
      ":memory": 1024
    },
  }
}
```

Please help!!!

Comment: Can you provide more information about what went wrong?

Comment: Initially I had vm's running and I had the .vmdk files for all the vm's as backup. I had openAM running on all the vm's and something went wrong with the configuration of OpenAM. So I decided to destroy all the Vagrant machines and bring them up from the backup which I made earlier. I used Vagrant destroy command to delete all the vms. There was no vms in the /home/vagrant/Virtual Box/vms. Later I placed the vm folders containing .vmdk files from backup in the same location (/home/vagrant/Virtual Box/vms) and ran vagrant up. After running vagrant up I'm getting the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this error and you can use this fix:

Delete folder project in vagrant

```
rm -rf /home/protobox/VirtualBox VMs/project_folder
```

Go to project folder:

```
cd /var/www/project_folder
```

Then restart vagrant:

```
vagrant destroy**maybe more**`vagrant destroy -f`
vagrant reload
```

Finally you start vagrant

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
```

Or you can refer to here: http://getprotobox.com/docs/issues/vbox_rename

Good luck!